# Modyfying a regex to restrict numeric range

Tags: regex

I am modifying a regex validator control. 
The regex at the moment looks like this:

```
(\d*\,?\d{2}?){1}$
```

As I can understand it allows for a number with 2 decimal places.

I need to modify it like this:

- The number must range from 0 - 1.000.000. (Zero to one million).
- The number may or may not have 2 decimals.
- The value can not be negative.
- Comma (`,`) is the decimal separator.
- Should not allow any thousand separators.

Comment: This is not a very good (or even correct) regex. I'd rather rewrite it completely than modifying it. Are you sure you want to use the comma as a decimal separator? Do you want to allow (or even require) dots as thousands separators?

Comment: Numer 'can' have or 'must' have 2 decimals?

Comment: Which bit is proving problematic? Have you looked at any of the "related" posts? This is not a new problem to StackOverflow!

Comment: @TimPietzcker I have updated the original message. The comma should be decimal separator but no thousand separators.

Comment: @Lucasus see the updated message. May or may not have 2 decimals.

Answer (score 2):

Try this regex:

```
^(((0|[1-9]\d{0,5})(\,\d{2})?)|(1000000(\,00)?))$
```

It accepts numbers like: `"4", "4,23", "123456", "1000000", "1000000,00"`, 
but don't accepts: `",23", "4,7", "1000001", "4,234", "1000000,55"`.

If you want accept only numbers with exactly two decimals, use this regex:

```
^(((0|[1-9]\d{0,5})\,\d{2})|(1000000\,00))$
```

Comment: @Tim, yep I've noticed this 5 secs after you :) Corrected

Comment: It's optional now. But old wersion worked too (it used alternative '|' with nothing instead of '?')

Comment: Oh, I see. I had overlooked the pipe character. But it's much better now. One last problem: This regex allows `1000000.99` which may or may not be desired. Probably not, but still, +1 for this.

Comment: That hasn't really made it much better. Now the scope of the alternation is wrong (you need another set of parentheses to separate the anchors `^` and `$` from the alternation), and the decimals are no longer optional (except in the case of `1000000`).

Comment: Not that easy to write regex with any errors :) I've corrected regex (but still testing it), I hope now it is ok.

Comment: Yay. Looks good. Not an easy problem, right? Let's hope we don't need to allow thousands separators :)

Comment: I don't know abut thousands separators, but the OP did say the *decimal* separator is `,`, not `.`. ;)

Comment: @Alan. Oh no, you are right. My performance is so bad today. I've corrected answer.

Comment: Wow. The experts are at work. Thanks guys! I see you checked that i updated the requirements. Can i test this regex?

Comment: Of course you can test it. And please give feedback if this regex is good or not.

Answer (score 0):

What about this one

```
^(?:\d{1,6}(?:\,\d{2})?|1000000)$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2ut4u)

It accepts between 1 and 6 digits and an optional fraction with 2 digits OR "1000000".

And it allows the number to start with zeros! (001 would be accepted)

`^` anchors the regex to the start of the string

`$` anchors the regex to the end of the string

`(?:)` is a non capturing group

Answer (score 0):

```
^(([0-9]|([1-9][0-9]{1,5}))(\.[0-9]{1,2})?)|1000000$
```